# 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'cssselect'

Tags: python, lxml

I am running python 2.7.2
I have lxml and cssselect installed

My code is

```
from lxml import etree, html
r = html.parse(start_url)
all_titles = r.cssselect('span.titles') #should return a list of results
all_urls = r.cssselect('span.links') #and this as well
```

I am scraping a webpage that has titles and their associated links.

But I run into this error:
'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'cssselect'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`ElementTree`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html) does not have `cssselect` method, while [`HtmlElement`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlElement-class.html) object have it.

Use [`ElementTree.getroot`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getroot) to get `HtmlElement` object:

```
r = html.parse(start_url).getroot()
```